# When I try to upload an image, it is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Visual Studio Code instead of codepen by the way. In a lesson, I was introduced to Global Variables. I have created one, under the "//Global Variable" comment called "image". I am able to access it anywhere. However, my code still is not working.

Does anybody know why?
Below is the JavaScript part of the HTML file. I have checked all my CSS and HTML code, and I am convinced the bug lies in the JavaScript code.

```
<script src="https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/image/SimpleImage.js">
</script>
<script>
    //Global Variable
    var image;
    //Function for uploading a file
    function upload() {
        image = new SimpleImage(fileinput);
        var imgcanvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var fileinput = document.getElementById("finput");
        image.drawTo(imgcanvas);
    }
    function makeGray() {
        for (var pixel of image.values()) {
            var avg = (pixel.getRed() + pixel.getGreen() + pixel.getBlue())/3;
            pixel.setRed(avg);
            pixel.setGreen(avg);
            pixel.setBlue(avg);
        }
        var imgcanvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        image.drawTo(imgcanvas);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you created the variable `fileinput` anywhere? I can see it's used in your `upload()` method: `image = new SimpleImage(fileinput);` but there's no initialisation of this variable in your script above 

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately just saying my code isn't working doesn't tell us anything of value without basic debugging details. What are you expecting to happen, what actually happens, what errors are thrown etc? Take a few minutes to thoroughly read [ask] and [mcve] then edit the question with properly detailed explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you used the fileinput variable before its declaration. Change your function to this:

```
//Function for uploading a file
function upload() {
    var imgcanvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("finput");
    image = new SimpleImage(fileinput);
    image.drawTo(imgcanvas);
}
```

I don't know if this is going to solve your problem since we don't have all the pieces but it definitely was a mistake.